# Javascript Bookmarklet Debugging

Tags: javascript, iframe, bookmarklet

Recently I'd like to develop a bookmarklet for my parents to help them reading some of english websites,the idea is when they are reading on websites,click the bookmarklet I created by using javascript,so every word or statement they picked by double click or select with mouse would be captured and send to a dict site to find translation,I finished one and test with some of websites,it's working on some sites but not all of them,I spend sometime debugging but couldn't figure out what caused the problem,so please advise,thanks in advance.

```js
javascript: (function() {
    document.onmouseup = MouseUp;

    function MouseUp(event) {
        var t;
        var w = window.innerWidth;
        var h = window.innerHeight;
        var dw = w * 0.7;
        var dh = h * 0.7;
        var x = event.clientX;
        var y = event.clientY;
        var os = 20;
        try {
            if (window.getSelection) {
                t = window.getSelection().toString()
            } else if (document.getSelection) {
                t = document.getSelection()
            } else if (document.selection) {
                t = document.selection.createRange().text
            }
            if (t.length > 1) {
                var dictWindow = document.createElement('div');
                dictWindow.setAttribute('id', 'dictwindow');
                dictWindow.style.border = 'thick solid #0000FF';
                dictWindow.style.zIndex = '1000';
                dictWindow.style.width = dw;
                dictWindow.style.height = dh;
                dictWindow.style.position = 'fixed';
                dictWindow.style.left = (x + dw + os > w) ? x - dw - os : x + os;
                dictWindow.style.top = (y + dh + os > h) ? y - dh - os : y + os;
                dictWindow.style.overflow = 'auto';
                dictWindow.style.backgroundColor = '#FFF';
                var closeSpan = document.createElement('span');
                closeSpan.innerHTML = 'Close';
                closeSpan.style.width = '50px';
                closeSpan.style.height = '20px';
                closeSpan.style.position = 'absolute';
                closeSpan.style.left = '2px';
                closeSpan.style.top = '2px';
                closeSpan.style.zIndex = '10001';
                closeSpan.style.backgroundColor = '#CCC';
                closeSpan.style.cursor = 'pointer';
                closeSpan.onclick = function() {
                    document.getElementById('dictwindow').remove()
                };
                var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
                iframe.src = 'http://www.dict.cn/' + t;
                iframe.style.width = '100%';
                iframe.style.height = '100%';
                iframe.style.zIndex = '999';
                iframe.style.position = 'absolute';
                dictWindow.appendChild(closeSpan);
                dictWindow.appendChild(iframe);
                document.body.appendChild(dictWindow)
            }
        } catch (e) {
            alert(e)
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: Example site and error message would be useful. Bookmarklets often do not work with iFrames due to same origin issues

Comment: I didn't get any error message,the only thing that I can tell is instead pop up the translation window,it seemed like the page scrolled to the end but nothing else,I was using chrome to debug but could not find any valuable information helps me to figure out the problem.

Comment: I tested my bookmarklet with 9to5mac.com,it works fine but others like stackoverflow.com, cnbc.com etc not working well,once I picked up a word,it scrolled down to the end of page and nothing else shown up.

Comment: It seems the position is off. On some pages you add the iframe in such a way it does not have room to expand